# Scikit-learn and Scipy yield diverging cosine distances -- after removing feature columns

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, distance

When we take an `N x M` matrix with N observations and M features, a common task is to compute pairwise distances between the N observations, resulting in an `N x N` distance matrix. The popular Python libraries `scipy` and `scikit-learn` both provide methods for performing this task and we expect them to yield the same results for metrics that both have implemented. The following function tests the equivalence for a given matrix called `arr`:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

def test_equivalence(arr: np.array, metric="cosine") -> bool:
    scipy_result = squareform(pdist(arr, metric=metric))
    sklearn_result = pairwise_distances(arr, metric=metric)
    return np.isclose(scipy_result, sklearn_result).all()
```

Now I happen to have this `1219 x 37652` array `arr` where each row sums to 1 (normalized) and `test_equivalence(arr)` yields True, as expected. That is, the `N x N` cosine-distance matrices returned by both libraries can be used interchangeably. However, when I cull the last `i` columns, `test_equivalence(arr[:, -i])` yields True **only up to a certain value** (which happens to be `i = 25676`). From this value onwards, the equivalence does not hold.

I am completely short of ideas why this is, any guidance? I may share the array as `.npz` file for debugging if someone can advise how, but maybe someone already has a premonition. The ultimate question will be, of course, which implementation should I be using?

I've also tested the failing `arr[:, -25675]` with these other metrics: `["braycurtis", "canberra", "chebyshev", "cityblock", "correlation", "euclidean", "hamming", "matching", "minkowski", "rogerstanimoto", "russellrao", "seuclidean", "sokalmichener", "sokalsneath", "sqeuclidean", "yule"]` out of which all except "correlation" were equivalent.

**Edit:** A reduced `(1219 x 96)` array that fails the equivalence test can be downloaded from https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/B19JbTL5aZ4pY3f/download and loaded via `np.load("tf_matrix.npz")["arr_0"]`.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the data. Maybe you can upload a dataset (preferably a minimal one that reprroduces the error). One thing I can imagine is that exceptional cases are handled differently by the libs. E.g. if the first 25676 coluzmns of your metrix are all zero, then in the cosine norm you get a division by 0. This exceptional case might be handled differently by the two libs. IF you then add a nnzero column, everything is fine again.

Comment: Thanks @yar, I've provided an example. No column or row sums to 0.

Comment: How different are the results? If they're just a little outside than the `isclose()` theeshold, both routines' rssults may be reasonable given the vagaries of floating-point calculations, and the difference might not matter for real applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few diagnostics you can try in this situation. One diagnostic you can try is to plot the places where the two methods of computing distance disagree.

```
# Modified version of test_equivalence() that returns boolean matrix of disagreements
def test_equivalence(arr: np.array, metric="cosine"):
    scipy_result = squareform(pdist(arr, metric=metric))
    sklearn_result = pairwise_distances(arr, metric=metric)
    return np.isclose(scipy_result, sklearn_result)
plt.imshow(test_equivalence(arr))
```

This gives the following plot:

[image: equivalence plot]

Note that it is True everywhere except for a horizontal line around 1200, and a vertical line around 1200. So it's not that the two methods disagree about all vectors - they disagree in all comparisons involving a particular vector.

Let's find out which column contains the vector that they disagree over:

```
>>> row, col = np.where(~test_equivalence(arr))
>>> print(col[0])
1168
```

Is there anything strange about vector 1168?

```
>>> print(arr[1168])
[1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23
 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23
 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23
 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23
 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23
 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23
 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23
 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23
 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23
 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23
 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23
 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23
 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23
 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23
 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23
 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23
 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23
 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23
 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23
 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23
 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23
 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23
 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23
 1.20000016e-23 1.20000016e-23]
```

This vector is very, very small. Is it unusually small compared to other vectors, though? You can test this by graphing the euclidean length of each vector by position within the array.

```
plt.scatter(np.arange(len(arr)), np.linalg.norm(arr, axis=1))
plt.yscale('log')
```

This plot shows that most vectors have a euclidean length of about 0.1, except one vector, which is 20 orders of magnitude smaller. It's vector 1168 again.

[image: log plot of vector norms]

To check this theory about small vectors causing the problem, here is an alternate way of showing the problem. I took your array, and repeatedly simplified it until I had a test case which was as simple as possible, but still showed the issue.

```
arr_small = np.array([[1, 0], [1e-15, 1e-15]])
print(test_equivalence(arr_small))
print(squareform(pdist(arr_small, metric="cosine")))
print(pairwise_distances(arr_small, metric="cosine"))
```

Output:

```
[[ True False]
 [False  True]]
[[0.         0.29289322]
 [0.29289322 0.        ]]
[[0. 1.]
 [1. 0.]]
```

I declare two vectors, one with coordinates (1, 0), and the other with coordinates (1e-15, 1e-15). These should have an angle of 45 degrees between them. In cosine distance terms, that should be [1 - cos(45 degrees) = 0.292](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1+-+cos%2845+degrees%29). The pdist() function agrees with this calculation.

However, pairwise_distances() says the distance is 1. In other words, it says that the two vectors are orthogonal. Why does it do this? Let's look at the definition of cosine distance to understand why.

[image: cosine distance definition]

<sub>Image credit: SciPy documentation</sub>

In this equation, if either u or v contain all zeros, then the denominator will be zero, and you'll have a division by zero, which is undefined. What pairwise_distances() does in this case is that in any case where the euclidean length of a vector is "too small," then the length of the vector is replaced with 1 instead to avoid the division by zero. This causes the numerator to be much smaller than the denominator, so the fraction is 0, and the distance becomes 1.

More precisely, a vector is "too small" when the length of the vector is smaller than 10 times the [machine epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) for the relevant type, which is approximately 2.22e-15 for 64-bit floats. ([Source.](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1.3.2/sklearn/preprocessing/_data.py#L111))

In contrast, pdist() does not contain any code to avoid this division by zero.

```
>>> print(squareform(pdist(np.array([[1, 0], [0, 0]]), metric="cosine")))
[[ 0. nan]
 [nan  0.]]
```

Comment: Amazing, I've learned a lot thanks to you, thanks for taking the time!